# From local ubuntu mirror, removing all packages of 20.04 only

Tags: ubuntu, mirror

I currently have local repo installed using `apt-mirror` as was described in [linuxtechi](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/) website. It has `deb-amd64` data of 2 versions of Ubuntu, namely, `20.04` and `22.04`. Now I would like to support only `22.04` and remove `20.04`. Is there a smart way to do this? I do not mind downloading the entire data again, if necessary, but do not wish to do the set up again. And if that isn't possible, what is the best way to recreate the site as I find `apt-mirror` being a little difficult to maintain (but the current setup seems to be stable now).

I am considering removal of directories `dists` and `pool` from `/home/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and the entries corresponding to `20.04` in `/etc/apt/mirror.list`. This will lead to removal of all mirrored files but the automated download script should get all the necessary data again. Inefficient, but I do not know how to remove only the files of `20.04`. There are only a few thousand files with the tag `-0ubuntu0.20.04` so file names are not very useful.

Thanks in advance for any feedback and help.

PS: I posted this question on serverfault but received no response in 2 days.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but FWIW, it might be better to ask on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Thank you. Will do that if I do not get any response in a day.